# Troubling interpreting the output from R package RCapture, open population model

Tags: r

I have been using R for a little while now, and can usually search for answers to my questions. This time I am stumped. I am using R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety" to analyze mark-recapture data. The code is located in package `RCapture`. We had four sampling occasions in which we captured and marked 48 individuals over a period of several months. Therefore, I wanted to run the data through an open population model. the `p*` notation is the sampling period, 0 and 1 were absent and present at that sampling period, and the frequency is how many were caught in that pattern (again, not sure how much depth is needed here).

```
p1 p2 p3   p4   freq
0   0   0   1   1
0   0   1   0   9
0   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   0   10
0   1   0   1   0
0   1   1   0   7
0   1   1   1   3
1   0   0   0   13
1   0   0   1   0
1   0   1   0   0
1   0   1   1   0
1   1   0   0   5
1   1   0   1   0
1   1   1   0   1
1   1   1   1   0
```

The output of `str(terp)`:

```
data.frame': 15 obs. of 5 variables: 
 $ p1 : int 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ... 
 $ p2 : int 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ... 
 $ p3 : int 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 ... 
 $ p4 : int 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ... 
 $ freq: int 1 9 0 10 0 7 3 13 0 0 ...
```

The code used was as follows:

```
op1=openp(terp, dfreq=TRUE)
```

The code ran fine, but I am trying to figure out why the output looks as it does. Normally, the output will give an estimate of the abundance with a standard error estimate, but the output I received gives an estimate with a 0 standard error, i.e. estimate = 26, standard error = 0.

```
           estimate  stderr
period 1        --      --
period 2        26       0
period 3        20       0
period 4        --      --
```

The final estimate of total population just seems to be the total number captured:

```
Total number of units who ever inhabited the survey area:
              estimate  stderr
all periods        49       0

Total number of captured units: 49
```

The capture probabilities have the same issue as the abundances, they are an estimate of 1 with no standard error. I am not sure if this is the right outlet, but I have looked all over for reasons this might be occurring. I wanted to verify the code is correct, and could this just be low sample size affecting the output?

Comment: Unless an expert in this area happens to come along you may be hard pressed to get an answer, as (outside of ecology) this is a somewhat  niche question.  Suggestions: (1) include *all* of the data, or at least enough to provide us with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) [follow link for advice on data presentation]. (2) you might want to show us `str(terp)`. (3) if you don't get useful advice here, you might try on r-sig-ecology@r-project.org

Comment: 'data.frame':   15 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ p1  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ p2  : int  0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ p3  : int  0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ p4  : int  1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ freq: int  1 9 0 10 0 7 3 13 0 0 ...
Ben, I was afraid of that. I should have edited the post to say that the data shown is all of the raw data. I tried to post to r-sig, but it got rejected with no explanation, I will definitely try again. Here was the output from str(terp). I am sorry, I cannot figure out the formatting in the comments section to insert the code